# Select all users from a table who buy 2 or more items from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MYSQL and have been setting up something basic, I have several tables
User, Purchase, Item
User and Item share keys, Purchase shares keys with Item, I want to basically find a query that allows me to see what users (uid) have bought 2 or more items

I was going to try

```
SELECT uid FROM user
SELECT pid FROM Purchase
SELECT iid FROM Item WHERE itype...
```

And then I get lost, sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: I think it is better to use join query to retrieve data from two table

Comment: You should provide other fields for `User`, `Purchase` and `Item`. Also, when you say bought 2 or more items, is it of the same item or could be different items? Let's say 2 or more Heinz Catsup or is it ok 1 Heinz Catsup and 2 bag of tea? I am asking this because of the `WHERE itype` in your question.

Comment: something like `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN .. ON ... GROUP BY uid HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said User and Item share keys.  If that means that each row in Item contains a uid then you can do this:

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(uid)
  FROM Item
  GROUP BY uid
  HAVING COUNT(uid) > 1
```